# How to capture barcode hex code keystrokes in an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oracle-apex

I have a Datalogic Memor10 barcode scanner which looks and acts a lot like an Android phone, except that additionally it has a barcode scanner in the front. The barcode scanner can be triggered by pressing a key on the side of the Memor10. It also has a feature it calls a Keyboard Wedge which is luckily enabled by default, since I was unable to figure out how to get its complicated settings to be changed. The Keyboard Wedge apparently causes any scanned barcode to also be typed as keystrokes; so that, for example, when you have an `input` tag on a web application it will type the barcode into that input as keystrokes.

This works great for simple barcodes, however the barcode I would like to scan is an South African drivers license barcode which is encrypted with RSA encryption and therefore the keystrokes returned could be any byte character. This is a problem, since keystrokes such as `Tab` and `Enter` would leave the input field or submit by default.

The included form tag is only to prevent Oracle Apex's native form submission.

I have tried unsuccessfully to prevent this and just get the byte codes as hex characters with a simple input screen in Oracle Apex. My Javascript/jQuery/HTML code is currently the following:

Static content region:

```
<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(0);">
   <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode">
</form>
```

On page load:

```
/*
$("#barcode").on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode.toString(16));
    e.preventDefault();
});
*/
$("#barcode").keypress(function(event) {
   console.log(event.which.toString(16));
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

However this does not work well, since `Tab` still leaves the input field and `Enter` works the first time and then stops working, only to start working again if you press another key inbetween. Not sure which other byte codes would cause issues. What code can I use to successfully capture the long string of byte codes sent as keystrokes to the input tag by the Memor10 barcode scanner? Or is there some other way of achieving this? I would like this to be a web application and not an Android native app.

Answer (score 1):

The `keypress` event is fired when a *character* value is pressed down. Also, it is deprecated. You should use the `keydown` event, which is fired for all keys.

```html
<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
/*$("#barcode").on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode.toString(16));
    e.preventDefault();
});*/

$("#barcode").on('keydown',function(event) {
   console.log(event.which.toString(16));
   event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

This first snippet will help you prevent the tab character from causing damage.

Next, to see if there are issues with other key codes, I wrote a script which will fire an event for all key codes from 0 to 256.

```js
$("#barcode").on('keydown',function(event) {
   console.log(event.keyCode.toString(16));
   event.preventDefault();
});

const el = document.getElementById('barcode')
for (let i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
  el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':i}));
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode">
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It seems to work. Now you can gather all key strokes in an array to recompose your bar code.

Comment: As you can see from my question I did initially use the `keyup` which is similar, but it was even worse than `keypress`. For A for example it would show the code twice once for `Shift` and one `a`.

Comment: @Superdooperhero have you tried my solution? It seems to work in the snippet. Keyup didn't work because the browser leaves the input when the tab is pressed down, not when it is released.

Comment: please precise what does the device input exactly. Is is the raw bytes of the barcode, or the text representation ?

Comment: I can confirm that your code completely fails to work. For the barcode 600640800134 which I can see type in the input when I scan it gives `e5 d`. Weirdly it gives an additional `e5` for any letter I type. If I scan the drivers license barcode I get `9 e5 (lots of e5) e5 d` even though I see lots of raw byte character codes in the input.